# Error on Webkit Transform

Tags: css, css-transforms

I am working on CSS3 and I got an error on this code:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0) !important;
```

The error is that `translate3d(0,0,0)` is not valid for the `-webkit-transform` property

Comment: who told you that it is not valid? the browser, or some css-validation site?

Comment: The is a red line under it and when I put the cursor on it the comment about it said that it is not valid

Comment: Which version of chrome are you using?

Comment: what browser and version are you using? this information is critical to answering the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);/* without !important */
```

Comment: every single code that has a wibkit-transform is not working and it has an error.

Comment: do you use Chrome 17 or Safari 5.1? these seems to support translate3d